# Kusto join two tables based on latest available date

Tags: join, kql

Is there a way to join two tables on Kusto, and join values based on latest available date from the second table?

Let's say we get distinct names from first table, and want to join values from the second table based on latest available dates.
I would also only keep matches from left column.

table1

```
names
-----
Alex
John
Mary
```

table2

```
name  weight   date
----- ------  ------
Alex. 160.    2023-01-20
Alex. 168.    2023-01-28
Mary. 120.    2022-08-28
Mary. 140.    2020-09-17
```

Sample code:

```
table1
|distinct names
|join kind=inner table2 on $left.names==$right.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let table1 = datatable(names:string)
[
    "Alex"
   ,"John"
   ,"Mary"
];
let table2 = datatable(name:string, weight:real ,["date"]:datetime)
[
    "Alex" ,160 ,datetime(2023-01-20)
   ,"Alex" ,168 ,datetime(2023-01-28)
   ,"Mary" ,120 ,datetime(2022-08-28)
   ,"Mary" ,140 ,datetime(2020-09-17)
];
table1
| distinct names
| join kind=inner (table2 | summarize arg_max(['date'], *) by name) on $left.names==$right.name
```

| names | name | date | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | Mary | 2022-08-28T00:00:00Z | 120 |
| Alex | Alex | 2023-01-28T00:00:00Z | 168 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA22QUUvDMBSF3wv9D5cwWCOJpFG2WumDr4K/oBTJ7LWLpimkETfZj7fNWpFuecm5ycc5yTHowaudwRQKqJVXYUisarHPe%20%200bWgclXEEwyJPBg8kaEaeu72d9Ytyx0FXj3FkZkN5YTj5MfhG3ex97lAZYCUZKCRVPm5et7jMA5ZuBLD5OpFC3nGRcinoFP%20HZdewjP5/5YDJhZvkIruC3S8wwcUDT7f0/M9zaXF0glr3Xts3D6G08eSj0xY%20ta0LbS06SKZCTtB/ta1y%20gdBuea1VYekXI8Z64rBDYXdMZhQ6CysDL772%20BZFCs3NhamXza%20mJSyAQAA)